# How to say something like “I trained every day to be a better runner”

Tags: translation, english-to-german, verb, word-order

How would you say something with this construction? “I did X (in order) to Y”. My thought for the sentence in the title was

> Jeden Tag trainierte ich ein besserer Läufer zu werden.

Does this resemble how you would say this, or is it way off? Also, is the word order correct?

Comment: I think it should be ein *besserer* Läufer

Comment: I would say *"Jeden Tag trainierte ich, um ein besserer Läufer zu werden."* or *"Ich trainierte jeden Tag, um ein besserer Läufer zu werden."*. ( *"um ... zu"* = *"(in order) to"*)

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan You are correct, I edited the question accordingly as that was not its main focus.

Answer (score 1):

> Jeden Tag trainierte ich, um ein besserer Läufer zu sein.
>
> Ich trainierte jeden Tag, um ein besserer Läufer zu sein.

*Um … zu* means  *(in order) to*.

If you want to say *to become a better runner* you have to use the futur composed with *werden (become)*, otherwise it is the Präsens *sein (to be).*

Comment: The focus is on the first words: `Jeden Tag...` has the focus on `daily`, the second one is just standard.

Comment: _Werden_ sounds better.

Comment: @MartinPeters But it has an other meaning. *to be a better runer* and *to get a better runner* is not the same